# Rails: Best way to integrate Facebook on project with multiple domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, internationalization

On my current project we planing to integrate Facebook for authentication. The site use different domains for i18n, sitenameineng.com sitenameinswe.se and so on.
Facebook only allows multiple domains with the same base URL and that's where the problems begin.
I could put up a new project for each language, but it feels incredibly unnecessary. What would be the best solution?

The only solution I can come up with is to create a new Facebook app for each language and then change the facebook app id and secret in my project depending on locale or is there a better solution?
If there is no better solution, how should I do to put app id and secret depending on locale?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What about creating something like a `proxy` app which provides an API for all your domains to work with?

Say: proxy.sitename.com contains the SDK, authentication, database handling, and redirects to the proper website. You can then make requests to your proxy which, in turn, calls the Facebook API endpoints using the provided access token. Sure, this can result in slight perf hit, but this is probably the best way to solve this.

Considering the nature of your project, you might also want to consider: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/

Comment: That would probably be the best solution. Unfortunately are my knowledge and experience zero when it comes to proxies and it would probably be too difficult for me to accomplish such solution.

Comment: I used proxy just as a term to describe what you would be doing. The idea is basically just redirecting the calls through one server/domain. So instead of calling graph.facebook.com you would be calling graph.yourdomain.com which then calls graph.facebook.com and return the result.

Comment: But wouldn't it be problem when i need to set the session to set current user? If a user signs in from site b that redirect to a and then redriect to b again when the call from facebook is done?

Comment: You would handle sessions on each of your individual domains. Actually, you would have the database handling on individual domains too, now that I think about it. You would use an intermediary domain to reroute API calls. I think this should be achievable, using the PHP SDK or raw GET and POST requests to the graph.facebook.com endpoint.